# Get the ID of the Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two ASP.NET Grid views, which contain an Image-button, which both call an Edit On-click event. the On-click event looks like:

```
protected void Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton ibtn1 = sender as ImageButton;

    using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((ImageButton)sender).Parent.Parent)
    {
        txtMessageID.ReadOnly = true;
        txtMessageID.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        txtReference.Text = row.Cells[6].Text;
        buttonClicked.Text = ibtn1.ID.ToString();
        popup.Show();
    }
}
```

which sole purpose is to fire off a ModalDialogBox, with key items from the grid view being clicked. My problem is that one of the grids doesn't have the Cells[6] (Reference) and therefore falls over. What i need to do is wrap a statement around this cell checking which grid (ID) the button click came from.

I'm not using Row-command, as this wouldn't allow for a single method call from multiple grids. My question is how do I obtain the Grid ID from the Image Button being clicked within this method (see above)?

Comment: Could you not just count the cells in a row and only do the 6 query if there's 6 cells or more?

Comment: and if the cells grow or shrink, my code falls over.. not sure that's the best approach. I can see that I have access to the ClientID, which can be set to static (GridName etc) but need to know how to access it from the method being called.

Comment: Ah, didn't realise that the cells numbers were variable outside of the 6+- scenario. You could always put the reference that you're getting in cell 6 into a hidden initial cell in your gridview. User doesn't see it but you know it's always there and can get the value using row.cells[0] or whatever. Obviously this will only work if you know you're going to have that data every time.

Comment: Yeah, data is driven from datable, and built on the fly. Hence why i need the GridView ID

Comment: I've edited my previous comment which might offer a solution.

Comment: Full Time, appreciate the suggestions, but I am using some JQuery code which will enable the end user to hide and show fields, unfortuantely this also shows hidden fields :-) The missing piece to this puzzle now, is to send the Name of the ImageButton being click, so I will look at the CommandArguments method

Comment: or even better the CommandName :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using the RowCommand of the Gridview, and then used the following to get what i need:

rotected void Edit(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton ibtn1 = sender as ImageButton;

```
    GridView grd = sender as GridView;

    string gridName = grd.ClientID;

    string buttonId = e.CommandName;

    using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer)
    {
        txtMessageID.ReadOnly = true;
        txtMessageID.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        if (gridName == "grdMessageDups")
        {
            txtReference.Text = row.Cells[6].Text;
        }
        buttonClicked.Text = ibtn1.ID.ToString();
        popup.Show();
    }
}
```